# Simple Centering of a DIV Using CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do something so astonishingly simple, and yet after pounding my head on the wall I'm unable to get the div that contains my navigation menu to center within the container. I would appreciate it if you'd have a look and let me know why it isn't working. I have a 1px border around the elements so you can see how the 'nav' div is staying left justified.

Here's a link to jsfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/glennw9/7vr7tovh/3/

```css
html, body {
    background-color:#F2EED6;
    width:900px;
    height:900px;
    border: 1px solid #630800;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#container {
    /*border: 1px solid #630800;*/
    width: 860px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #630800;
}


h1 {
    font-size: 2.5em;
    font-family: Georgia;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    color: #630800;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    text-align: center;
}

div.nav {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #630800;
    text-align: center;
}
ul.nav {
    width: 840
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
ul.nav, li.nav {
    list-style-type: none;
}
li.nav, a.nav {
    background: #354178;
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
li.nav, a.nav:hover {
    background: #4A5AA7;
    display:inline;
}
li {
    display:inline;
    padding: 10px;
}
a.active {
    background: white;
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="container">
         <h1>Edit Order Record</h1>

        <div class="nav">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a class="nav" href="inv-main.php">Main Page</a>

                </li>
                <li><a class="nav" href="prod-view-paged.php">View Products</a>

                </li>
                <li><a class="nav active" href="order-view-paged.php">View Orders</a>

                </li>
                <li><a class="nav" href="cat-view.php">View Categories</a>

                </li>
                <li><a class="nav" href="#Bot">Go to Bottom</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
</body>
```

Comment: See if [this link will help](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add `text-align: center;` to the `#container` element.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7vr7tovh/6/).

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking the text-align:center wouldn't work on a block type element. Silly me...

Answer (score 0):

You can center align it by simply two ways.

1. This "div.nav" class has inline-block. To make it center aligned with its parent, you have to use "text-align:center" to its parent.
2. Remove inline-block for "div.nav" class and add margin:0 auto in this class. It will be center aligned.

Answer (score 0):

What about this ([updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7vr7tovh/7/))?

```
div.nav {
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #630800;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[image]

If you want to consider using flex-box, you can do something like this too (see [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7vr7tovh/8/), and here's the [browser compatibility table](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)):

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>Thing</li>
        <li>Another thing</li>
        <li>Yet another</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

[image]

And lastly, here's a list of ways to center stuff:

- Set this on the child element: `{ margin-left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%) }`
- If the child element is `block` do this: `{ margin: 0 auto }`
- Or, on the parent element, do: `{ text-align: center }`

Answer (score 0):

you have a lot of options mentioned above. This too counts as one of them: `position: absolute;
 left:50%;
 margin-left: (half of the width of the div u wish to center)`

Remember, set your parent element/div to relative.

Answer (score 0):

remove the margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; and change that to margin:auto; in html,body{}
 and add text-align:center in #container.

```
html, body {
background-color:#F2EED6;
width:900px;
height:900px;
border: 1px solid #630800;
/* margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;*/
margin: auto;
```

}

```
 #container {
    /*border: 1px solid #630800;*/
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #630800;
    text-align:center;
}
```

just edit the css part. and it will generate the output like this:

[image]